# Problema con arreglo

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

tengo un problema,  estoy creando un buscador, el problema es que al momento de buscar solo muestra un resultado con el filtro escrito en el buscador..

```
 public function search(Request $request) {




    $registros = Registro::where('cliente', 'LIKE', "%{$request->search}%")->get();

    $digits1 = Rawson::where('cliente', $registros->pluck('cliente'))->get();
    $digits2 = Electrodomesticos::where('cliente', $registros->pluck('cliente'))->get();

    foreach ($digits1 as $v1) {
    
        $uno = $v1;

    }

    foreach ($digits2 as $v2) {
    
        $dos = $v2;

    }


    $digits = [$uno, $dos];


    return view('posts.results', compact('digits'))->with(['search' => $request->search])->render();
}
```

Al hacer `dd($digits2);` obtengo 5 resultados...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al hacer `dd($dos);`    (foreach) obtengo:  1 solo resultado y ese es el problema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Como puedo hacer para que muestre los 5 valores del resultado correctamente en el buscador?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esos **foreach** están mal hechos, pues solo conservan, en las variables **$uno** y **$dos**, el valor del último ciclo pues en cada ciclo las estás sobreescribiendo en lugar de agregarlas a una variable de array.

Cámbialos por esto:

```php
$digits = [];
foreach ($digits1 as $v1) {
    $digits[] = $v1;
}
foreach ($digits2 as $v2) {
    $digits[] = $v2;
}
```

y elimina esta línea:

```
$digits = [$uno, $dos];
```

a ver si con eso lo consigues. Ya nos dirás si te ha funcionado.

Comment: Si funcionó perfecto